# Implementing step progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, gvnix

I have the following code in my html page to implement a simple step progress bar

```
<ol class="progtrckr" data-progtrckr-steps="5" id="stepBar">
    <li class="progtrckr-done"><a href="documents?form" style="color: black;">Order Processing</a></li>
    <li class="progtrckr-done">Pre-Production</li>
    <li class="progtrckr-done">In Production</li>
    <li class="progtrckr-done">Shipped</li>
    <li class="progtrckr-todo">Delivered</li>
</ol>
```

With the following CSS

```
ol.progtrckr {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

ol.progtrckr li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3em;
}

ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="2"] li { width: 49%; }
ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="3"] li { width: 33%; }
ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="4"] li { width: 24%; }
ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="5"] li { width: 19%; }
ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="6"] li { width: 16%; }
ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="7"] li { width: 14%; }
ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="8"] li { width: 12%; }
ol.progtrckr[data-progtrckr-steps="9"] li { width: 11%; }

ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 4px solid yellowgreen;
}
ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo {
    color: silver; 
    border-bottom: 4px solid silver;
}

ol.progtrckr li:after {
    content: "\00a0\00a0";
}
ol.progtrckr li:before {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -2.5em;
    float: left;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 1em;
}
ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-done:before {
    content: "\2713";
    color: white;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    height: 1.2em;
    width: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 1.2em;
}
ol.progtrckr li.progtrckr-todo:before {
    content: "\039F";
    color: silver;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    bottom: -1.6em;
}
#stepBar {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

How can I move the step bar only if the user has some other values saved in the database, known that I'm using `gvNix`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help:

You have control over you step bar using `progtrckr-done` and `progtrckr-todo` classes for the `li` element. So in your server side scripting language, whatever it is ( maybe `php` ), try to add the appropriate class to `li`s to control how they show for each user, regarding values set in you database